# Cannot Access Rails Server From Outside LAN

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first post here.  I have a rails server I'm running on a dedicated server that I have jail shell access to.  I can start up a rails server and access it just fine using the text-based browser elinks running in that jail shell using both internal and public IP's.  However, I cannot access the rails server from outside that chrooted environment.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on?  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the followings:

1. Check if your LAN is protected by a
   firewall, most router has a firewall
   inside and they will block many
   ports.
2. Assuming you are running
   script/server, check the firewall if
   port 3000 is allowed.
3. I dont think you are using
   apache/nginx with passenger/mongrel,
   are you? if yes check the firewall
   if port 80 is allowed.
4. Since you said that the dedicated
   server has a public IP, i am
   assuming that port forwarding on the
   firewall is configured correctly.
5. You have to access your rails server
   using
   http://your_server_public_ip:3000.

Hopefully those checks help you troubleshoot the problem

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The router is not in my control, so I'll talk with my host.  However, my http server is accessable just fine from anywhere.
From inside the shell, I can access http://publicip.com:3010.  However, from outside, the connection times out.